# Compare arrays and create new array Android SDK

Tags: java, android, arrays

I have two arrays "tags" and "selected" the tags array is static and depending on what the user selects the "select" array values will be set to true or false.

I want to compare the tags array and the select array and the "select" array positions that have true I want to pull out the correspoding position of the "tags" array and bulid a new array.

```
  private String[]  tags     = new String[] { "Bob", "Tom", "Mike", "Smith" };
  private boolean[] selected = new boolean[tags.length];
      public String[] selected_tags;

for (int i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
    if (selected[i] == true){
       selected_tags[i] = tags[i];
    }
```

I am not sure if I am doing this correctly because I feel like I would have empty spots in my selected_tag array. If there is a better way of doing this I am open to suggestions.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`public String[] selected_tags = new String[tags.length]`

Everything you say and you did is fine and reasonable. Just make sure all of them are of the same size. (see above)